# How to get min value from set

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have this table:

```
Profile_id  Phase_id   order
30087853    30021628    525
30087853    30021635    523
30087853    30021673    122
30087853    30021703    521
```

from the above I would like to get profile_id along with this phase_id, which has lowest order_num, so the outcome will be like:

```
Profile_id  Phase_id   order
30087853    30021673    122
```

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? (Part of) The answer is in your question.

Comment: Hint:  `ORDER BY` and something to limit the output to one row.

Comment: Which DBMS you are using ? tag that first !

Comment: Are you always querying a specific Profile_id?

Comment: Never, this is just a scrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify your DBMS so this is standard SQL:

```
select profile_id, phase_id, "order"
from (
   select profile_id, phase_id, "order", 
          row_number() over (partition by profile_id order by "order") as rn
   from the_table
) t
where rn = 1;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/MAUV44954

Comment: This gives me max value, I want min.

Comment: @misio_jasio: what data type is `order`

Comment: it's NUMBER(10,0)

Answer (score 1):

Without a sub-query or self-join you can use also this one:

```
SELECT Profile_id, MIN("order") as "order", 
    MIN(Phase_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY "order") AS Phase_id 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Profile_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

CREATE TABLE #table(Profile_id INT,  Phase_id INT, _order INT)
INSERT INTO #table(Profile_id ,  Phase_id , _order )
SELECT 30087853,30021628,525 UNION ALL
SELECT 30087853,30021635,523 UNION ALL
SELECT 30087853,30021673,122 UNION ALL
SELECT 30087853,30021703,521

SELECT *
FROM #table T1
JOIN 
(
   SELECT Profile_id ProfileId, MIN(_order) [order]
   FROM #table
   GROUP BY Profile_id
) A ON T1.Profile_id = ProfileId AND T1._order = [order]

Comment: That does not work. It looks for a minimal order_num value in whole table, then matches it with each profile_id. If any profile_id does not have phase with minimal order_num, then returns nothing, which is wrong.

Comment: In your question not mentioned anywhere based on profile_id.You just asked min value only.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but still nothing. Second answer gives just a combination of profile_id and order_num, I need profile_id, phase_id and order_num altogether.

Comment: What is your expected result,based on profile_id or anything else

Comment: I need profile_id along with this phase_id, which has lowest order_num.